# Like count increased dramatically/uniformly across site

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I implemented FB OG tags site wide within our site's templates about a week ago. However, I don't think I did it properly, as every OG property has the homepage URL, title, etc. regardless of the page (since they're in the templates, as opposed to page level).

Now I noticed our Like count has increased dramatically & uniformly on many pages of our site. Pages that only had a few likes a week ago (e.g. our homepage: http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/) or no likes now all have 58. I removed the OG tags from the templates yesterday (except for the homepage), and nothing changed. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Post some sample code

Comment: We use the standard FB Like plugin code created by their generator. Our FB OG tags are as follows:                                                        <meta property="og:title" content="Surety Bond Quotes Online | JW Surety Bonds" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="113203846159"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/" />
<meta property="og:image"content="http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/images/jw-fb-big.jpg"/>